Trigger Gitlab CI pipeline on merge
my .gilab-ci.yml file contains this:
deploy_to_prelive:
  artifacts: {}
  tags:
    - mytag
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy"
  environment:
    name: prelive
    url: https://example.com
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "prelive"'

while i create a merge request from another branch into this branch, the script runs.
But i expect to run the script only when i approve the merge and hit the "Merge" button.
Are there any rules that i can use for that?

If you wish to trigger this pipeline when merge has been done on your prelive branch, you should change the trigger rule.
deploy_to_prelive:
  artifacts: {}
  tags:
    - mytag
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy"
  environment:
    name: prelive
    url: https://example.com
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "prelive" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'

